# Proj4js, transformations forward and back - to big inaccuracy

Tags: coordinate-systems, coordinate-transformation, map-projections, proj4js

I use Proj4js v.2.3.3 to transform coordinates between two projections. The definitions of the projections I've found on spatialreference.org therefore I think it's ok.
If I transform point coordinates (pstart) from 1st projection to 2nd and back to 1st (pend) then pend and pstart differ too much - about 70m in one of the coordinates.
My code looks like:

```
var p3857 = "+proj=merc +lon_0=0 +k=1 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs";
var p2180="+proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=19 +k=0.9993 +x_0=500000 +y_0=-5300000 +ellps=GRS80 +units=m +no_defs";

pstart=[2450639.368,6801358.149]
p=proj4(p3857,p2180,pstart);
pend=proj4(p2180,p3857,p);
```

pend after that equals:

```
[2450639.3686302807, 6801287.767802416]
```

Did I do something wrong? 
Could somebody help me in this issue?
Thank you everybody for interest my problem